# Why is this if statement always returning true

Tags: sql, if-statement, triggers

Here is the trigger...

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_rejectNoTitle] 
ON  [dbo].[FMQI] 
  FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE TITLE = '')
   BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    RAISERROR('Missing TITLE',10,1)
    ROLLBACK TRAN

   END
GO
```

As you can see I want to reject an insert or update when the TITLE field is an empty string. I cannot figure out why the if statment always resolves to true even when the TITLE is not empty and the insert or update is rejected.

UPDATE: PROBLEM SOLVED

Lajos set me on the right path. This is how I fixed it...

```
DECLARE @Title VARCHAR(45)
SELECT @Title = TITLE FROM inserted
IF @Title = ''
   BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    RAISERROR('Missing TITLE',10,1)
    ROLLBACK TRAN

 END
```

Comment: Empty string and `NULL` are quite different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking whether there are any records in your `inserts` table which has empty string for `title`. I suppose that the condition is true because you have at least such a record all the time.

What I believe you wanted to do is to check whether the inserted or updated record's `title` is empty string. You should check whether `new.title` is an empty string instead of searching in the whole table for such a record.

Comment: Thanks Lajos. You set me straight. I didn't use new, however. See my updated post to see how I changed my code.